# How to view/monitor another WSUS server from an existing WSUS server?

Tags: security, updates, wsus

**Scenario:**

I work for an organisation which has an office in the UK and another (smaller) office in Kenya. Our UK office has a WSUS server which sends out updates to every computer on the domain (this includes the computers in Kenya).

However, we recently installed a WSUS server in the Kenya office to roll out updates to all computers located in Kenya.

So now I am looking at two different servers to manage and monitor WSUS.

**My question is:**

Is it possible - and if so - how do I manage or monitor both WSUS from one server? The aim is to monitor the Kenya WSUS server from the UK server without being logged into both.

*Note - Running Windows Server 2008R2 on both servers*

Edit:

[image: WSUS]

So our external IT company managed to do it for us. The picture above is what I wanted to achieve, first red line is Kenya server and the second red line is our UK server. I can manage both WSUS's under one WSUS console.

Comment: That depends entirely on what exactly you are using to "monitor" what.

Comment: I've edited the post. I believe they used MMC to do this - not sure. I will add an answer when I find out.

Comment: Yes, they did use MMC. Most MMCs allow remote access by default, you can add additional machines by right clicking the top of the tree and selecting "Connect to another computer".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean  a single Management interface for administrating the servers, then you could use Windows Admin Center or an RDP manager.